# How might I setup Kendo UI in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

How might I setup Kendo UI in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta That is the best edit I have ever seen.

Comment: I do what I can, @Marty.

Comment: how to install Kendo Ui so that we can start developing for Mobile web

Comment: Funny because I see pretty real question and even more real (because) useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check this sample application like [Kendo UI and ASP.NET WebForms : Building a Task Manager](http://Kendo%20UI%20and%20ASP.NET%20WebForms%20%3a%20Building%20a%20Task%20Manager) and here is the steps to start working with this.

```
- In Visual Studio, create a new ASP.NET Web application.
- Download Kendo UI.
- From the Kendo UI download, I copied the following files into the TaskManager/Scripts folder:     
     1.js/jquery.min.is   
     2.js/keno.all.min.js
- In the TaskManager application I created a new folder called "kendo" in the /Content folder.

 - From the Kendo UI download, copy the following files / folders into the /Content:     
    1.styles/kendo.common.min.css    
    2.styles/kendo.silver.min.css   
    3.styles/Silver (folder)
```

Inclue these in head section:

```
<head>
<title></title>
    <link href="Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json.extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

go for the [Codeplex - Kendo UI ASP.NET Sample Applications](http://kendouiaspnetsamples.codeplex.com/) for the samples and usage of Kendo.

Answer (score 2):

Simple All you Need is this

Getting Set Up
To get started create a new ASP.Net Empty Web Application.

[image]

Note: You can really use any web based project template you like, in this walkthrough I just chose to start with nothing. :)

Once the project loads, fire up the NuGet Package Manager Console.

Here :[NuGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27iEx.png) NuGet is a Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to install and update third-party libraries and tools in Visual Studio.(Like J query and Kendoui Files)

Add JQuery to the project using the command:

Install-Package jQuery

Add KendoUI to the project using the command:

Install-Package KendoUIWeb

Once you run both of these NuGet commands, the solution explorer should look like this:

[image]

Source :[Check it out](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-20/getting_started_with_kendo_ui_and_openaccess_orm.aspx)